# Undefined reference error in a C program

Tags: c, file, function, undefined-reference

I wrote a C program `pgm.c`. It contains a function `readfile.so`. Also I wrote a header file `do.h`. Then I wrote this `readfile` function in a separate program `ini.c` and included `do.h` to this program too. When I compiled `pgm.c` I got the error `"pgm.c:(.text+0x2e): undefined reference to readfile"`

My codes are :

```
do.h
    extern int readfile( FILE *in );

pgm.c
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include"do.h"
    int main(int argc,char **argv)
    {
     FILE *in;
     in=fopen(argv[1],"r");
     readfile(in);
    }

ini.c
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <limits.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <float.h> 
    #include"do.h"
    int c;
    int readfile( FILE *in )
    {
    while( c == '#' || c == '\n' )  
    {
      if( c == '#' ) 
       {
        while( ( c = getc(in) ) != '\n' );
       }
      if( c == '\n' ) 
       c = getc( in ); 
     }
      if( c == EOF )
      break;
      else
      {
      printf("hai");
      }
    }
    return 1;
    }
```

Is there any error in my programs?
compiling by `gcc pgm.c`

Comment: no need to declare function `extern`, they're extern by default

Comment: where is the command line you use to compile & link ? add the complete line, because it looks like you don't compile and link with "ini.c"

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 4):

`C` is case sensitive;

```
extern int readfile( FILE *in );
```

doesn't declare the same function as;

```
int readFile( FILE *in )
```

Pick a casing and use it everywhere for the same function.

Comment: i tried..change `int readfile( FILE *in );` in do.h.but again got same eroor

Comment: It's implementation-defined as to whether linking is case-sensitive or not.

Comment: Did you read the comments below your question? Your problems are not only in the code

Comment: @user39133 Try changing `int readFile( FILE *in )` to `int readfile( FILE *in )`

Comment: @user39133 You also need to compile with `gcc pgm.c ini.c`

Answer (score 0):

Also you need to check the return value of `fopen`.

If it returns `NULL` then your function `readfile` (depending on capitalization) will crash